# jQuery - .get works for 1 URL but not another

Tags: jquery

I have 2 URLs which I tried to get, using jQuery's .get feature, and the first link worked perfectly, however the second wouldn't append data to the div.

```js
//Locate the input box
var URL = $('#download');
//When button gets pressed
function downloadURL(){
//Get the URL from the input box
var downloadURL = URL.val();
//Get the contents of the JSON on the website linked
      $.get(downloadURL, 
   //add it to the output div
          function(data){
               $("#output").append(data)
          }
      );
//Tell me that it has actually accepted the URL
alert(downloadURL);
}
```

```html
<p> <input type="text" name="download" id="download" placeholder="Download URL"></p>
<button onclick="downloadURL()">Test</button>                          
<div id="output"></div>
```

The 2 URLs I tried were: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TemporalReality/modpacks/master/packs/ingenuity.json and http://widget.mcf.li/mc-mods/minecraft/224791-blood-magic.json

Any ideas why it works for one URL, but not the other? Or a better way to do this?

Comment: What the guy above me said is correct. The only way you can get around it is by requesting the data from a server with something like php or server side script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second URL is coming back as an `object` instead of a `string`. `$.append` expects a DOM object or a string.

If you really aim to append it that way, you can stringify it.

```
urls = [];
urls.push("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TemporalReality/modpacks/master/packs/ingenuity.json");
urls.push("http://widget.mcf.li/mc-mods/minecraft/224791-blood-magic.json");

$(urls).each(function(i, item){
  $.get(item, function(data){
    console.log(typeof data, item); // <-- watch the console
    if (typeof data === "object") {
      data = JSON.stringify(data);
    }
    $("#output").append(data).append('<hr>');
  });
});
```

Presuming you want to do something more interesting with it, you can leave the object alone and convert the string into an object with `JSON.parse` or  `$.parseJSON`.

```
if (typeof data === "string") {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
}
console.dir(data);
```

Comment: +1 to you, you actually bothered testing both links, and they both seem to work, just one doesn't identify itself as JSON so it's not parsed by jQuery, the string comes unparsed. There's a much easier way to solve that issue, just add a datatype as the last argument for `$.get`, and jQuery will parse it regardlessly, like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/a1n635ed/

Comment: Thanks so much, this is perfect <3

Comment: Glad it helped. And good point @adeneo. If you're using jQuery already, might as well go for it.