# Angular grabbing JSON params with $http.get for one url but on another

Tags: angularjs, json, rest, service

I'm new with Angular and trying to get some basic UI stuff going. I have a RESTful Spring service up and running. When I curl my service :

```
curl http://myPersonalSite.com:1313/service/event?id=1
```

I get a JSON response containing stuff including an "id", "description", etc. 
Using the identical code, but switching out the URL for the one given in an example I'm following

```
curl http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting
```

I also get a JSON response with "id", and "content". 
The example url results in the ID showing up when I run

```
spring run app.groovy
```

... but when I switch it out for my service URL, the id is not displayed. It doesn't seems to be able to get any info off the JSON response from my service. What am I missing here?!?

/public/index.html :

```
<html ng-app="demo">
<head>
    <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="hello.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="Hello">
        <p>The ID is {{event.id}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

/public/hello.js :

`angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting').   // this works
     //$http.get('http://myPersonalSite.com:1313/service/event?id=1').  // this doesn't work
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.event = response.data;
        });
});`

app.groovy  - simply :

`@Controller class JsApp { }`

... and then I run  `spring run app.groovy` and the example URL renders the id fine in the browser but my URL renders the page but there is no id. Again, curl for both URLs returns JSON which both contain and "id" key. I have read up a bit on JSON strings vs objects, and that doesn't seem to be the issue, here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

note - the following thread is similar, but slightly different [jQuery - .get works for 1 URL but not another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073082/jquery-get-works-for-1-url-but-not-another)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your request is blocked by CORS policy. You can check your browser console if there is any error message like "...has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".

The rest-service response actually set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin if you check the network tab of Chrome.

Browser will block ajax request if the requested resource's domain is different with the page domain and no proper Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not set at server side.